# How can I to pass options (or Load) class to a new package? Is it possible?

Tags: macros, package-writing, class-options

I'm planning to build a new package, which I call `abntstyle`, that can implement Brazilian norms of writing academic works. There is already a class called `abnTeX2` that does this. This class is evolving and improving every day as it continues to be under active development. However, this class has many new definitions (macros) that are not common in most classes or packages, which ends up being a problem, because if the user wants to change the format of his academic work by simply change of the class, it will occur, inevitably, errors due to these new macros (that only exist in `abnTeX2`), thus forcing the user to a tedious scan of his TeX source to readapt it to the new class.

My idea is that this new package should be able to use the minimum of new definitions (macros). In this sense, I would like to prioritize the use of the most diverse existing definitions in the most diverse packages and classes already available so that the new package is compatible with any class. That's the reason by that why I choose to make a package instead of a new class.

The `memoir` class, for example, has some interesting macros that I'd like to move into this new package. The environments `titlingpage` and `adjustwidth`, native to the `memoir` class, are examples of existing macros that can be useful in the development of this new package. So I would like to be able to use them without having to make new definitions, but only, if possible, invoke them from the `memoir` class.

Researching about it, I found in some class models that the `\LoadClass{<class name>}` command is sometimes used to call a class within another, so making its macros and options available to the new class: it was that the developers of the `abnTeX2` class did -- they loaded the `memoir` class. As can be seen from the minimal example below, I tried to use the `\LoadClass{<class name>}` command to call the `memoir` class into the package, but as expected, there was an error. I don't know if there's a way to do this, calling a class to a package, but if it's possible, I'd like to try. It is this attempt that motivates this title question.

Below is a minimal example.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     Identitication     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{abntstyle}[%
   2023/02/17 v1 Standard ABNT rules to typesseting of Academic Works%
]%
%\ProvidesFile{name}[release information]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     Initial   Code     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Declaration of Options %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareOption*{%
   \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{memoir}%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Execution of Options  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    Package  Loading    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\RequirePackage{geometry}
%   \geometry{vdivide={30mm,*,20mm},hdivide={30mm,*,20mm}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    Special Commands    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\LoadClass{memoir}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{abntstyle}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       Main  Code       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you intend to do. Do you want to pass on the options of `memoir` to it automatically if they are provided to your package? Or do you programmatically want to copy macros/functions from `memoir` into your package? Please note that if your package wants to pass on options to `memoir` the only way this would reliably work would be if your package is always loaded before `memoir`. All in all I have to ask: Why don't you make a new class instead?

Comment: it is hard to guess what you mean, a package or class option is not a separate unit of code that can be loaded or has any meaning outside that package. It is just a list of names that may be detected in the package option argument which then may trigger a change in package loading

Comment: My idea for this new package is that it should be able to use the minimum necessary new definitions. In this sense, I would like to prioritize the use of the most diverse existing definitions in the most diverse packages and classes already available so that it is compatible with any existing class. The memoir class, for example, has environments such as `titlingpage` and `adjustwidth`. These environments can be useful in the development of the package. Thus, I would like to be able to use them without having to make new definitions, but only, if possible, to invoke them from the memoir class.

Comment: While this might be theoretically possible (by writing arbitrarily complicated TeX code that is able to execute TeX within TeX to find the relevant definitions) this is neither practically feasible nor would it have decent performance. So to summarize this: No, not possible.

Comment: Keep in mind that TeX has no namespaces whatsoever, so something like `from math import pi` as you could do in Python isn't possible in TeX.